# Delete old branches that don't have opened pull requests

Tags: git, bitbucket

To clear repo I need auto script for autodeleting old branches, but I don't want delete old branches that have pull request from it. I have an idea to use ls-remote, find hashes of branches' head commits and pr's head commits and don't delete branches that:

1. Branch head equals PR head.
2. PR have only line in ls-remote pull-request/X/from that means it wasn't merged.
   This way looks very complexity.

How can I delete old branches that don't have opened pull-requests from it, using bash-scripts?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Since you tagged this with Bitbucket, I recommend using the bitbucket API to get all the pull requests of a repo: [/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.17.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp299). The sample response (click on the "expand" for a 200 response) has a `fromRef` and `toRef`, so you could possibly use the `fromRef` to get the source branch of the PR and cross-reference that with your other branches. I don't have time to try it though (and not keen on doing it with bash). Good luck.

Comment: thanks for variant looks nice, but I want try to do it using only git commands

Comment: Note, you need the list of branch names for all open PRs from bitbucket. Simply matching tip commits won't always work. Suppose you have 3 branches all on the same commit ID, and one of them has an open PR; you wouldn't know which one you could delete without enumerating the list of all open PRs and their source branches.